# Why is CH2Br2 more polar than CH3I?

Tags: organic-chemistry, inorganic-chemistry, halides

According to my textbook (A Level Chemistry a for OCR Student Book, Pages 84-5) $\ce{CH2Br2}$ is more polar than $\ce{CH3I}$. The molecules are both polar, they both contain different bonded atoms, and the bonded atoms have different electronegativities but why is $\ce{CH2Br2}$ MORE polar than $\ce{CH3I}$?

Comment: Why not? Br is clearly more electronegative than I.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As stated in the comments, $\ce{Br}$ is more electronegative than $\ce{I}$ (and that is a factor). Also, you have two polar bonds ($\ce{C}-\ce{Br}$) instead of just one ($\ce{C}-\ce{I}$) and, as a first approximation, dipoles due to bonds tend to add like vectors.